# boost: vector256.hpp: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am using boost 1.66 on Ubuntu 16.04, and cmake 3.9.5.
I come across the following error when I do some refactoring work on my application code, not on boost :) :

```
usr/include/boost/mpl/vector.hpp:37:1: fatal error: boost/mpl/vector/vector256.hpp: No such file or directory
 #   include BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(boost/mpl/vector/AUX778076_VECTOR_HEADER)
```

looks like `AUX778076_VECTOR_HEADER` is `vector256.hpp` here? And indeed there's no such `vector256.hpp` in `boost/mpl/vector/` dir.

It's probably that my refactoring work caused this but I didn't touch any cmake files and all I did was pulling some common parts out from code to make it a base class.

Anyone might be able to shed light on this?

You can find this `vector.hpp` here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/mpl/vector.hpp

**EDIT:**
These are the modules that I include for it `set( ${PROJECT_NAME}_BOOST_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES thread system filesystem date_time program_options )`. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPL distribution includes only up to 50 something (do not remember exactly how much) type list entries for preprocessed vectors (and other type list containers).

If you need longer vectors, you'd have to create those files yourself - luckily, it's just copy/paste.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you saying the `256` is the number of  "type list entries for preprocessed vectors"?

Comment: @Henry, just by convention, but yes.

Comment: I don't understand why this matters in my case. There's no logical changes in my code nor new functions, why this was not a problem before?

Comment: @Henry I have no idea what did you do with your code and how did you rearrange it. I know that this is the case with preprocessed vectors in MPL. May be you didn't use preprocessed vectors before?

Comment: I have been using them. I didn't add any vector code though,  I did move some of the vector code around. The vector looks like this: `struct transition_table : boost::mpl::vector<.....>{}`. I didn't change the types in it, they are way less than 50.

Comment: It doesn't work even after I added `vector256.hpp` to that dir.

Comment: @Henry looks like **that** dir is not that.

Comment: Can I ask you a follow-up question? Is there a way to avoid adding my own version of `vector256.hpp` and such to the boost package? It seems that adding these extra files are not so portable. (I don't wanna change the basic logic of my program as well)

Comment: @Henry Did you look into this? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/cfg-no-preprocessed-headers.html